# Why is the MouseListner not working in my Java-JFrame project?

Tags: java, jframe

So I am trying to make a TicTacToe game in Java with JFrame and trying to implement a MouseListener so the player can click on the squares. I found one method on the internet but cant figure out why its not working for me. What I already did is I created a frame and draw the grid and background color. Maybe I missed something? Thanks for your time.

```
import java.awt.*;  
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class Main extends JFrame
{   
    
    public static JFrame root = new JFrame("TicTacToe");

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        
        int[] board = {
            0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0
        };


        root.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(232,209,197));
        
        TicTacToeCanvas Canvas = new TicTacToeCanvas(board);  
        root.add(Canvas);
        root.setSize(915,939);
        root.setVisible(true); 
        root.setResizable(false);
        root.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        root.pack();

        MouseEventClass mouseEvents = new MouseEventClass(root);
    }
}

class MouseEventClass implements MouseListener{
    
    public MouseEventClass(JFrame frame){
        frame.addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        System.out.println("Click");
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Myself, I wouldn't add a MouseListener to the JFrame but rather would add it to the component or components held within the JFrame, possibly your TicTacToeCanvas component. Other notes: 1) you're over-complicating your mouse listener and how you're adding it to a component. 2) I hope that your TicTacToeCanvas does not exted Canvas but rather extends JPanel. 3) Learn and follow Java naming conventions -- all variable names should start with a lower-case letter. 4) For better answers, create and post a [mre] with  your question (check out the link).

Comment: Would it not be a whole lot easier to use a grid of ```JButton``` ?

Comment: @g00se: nah, I would use JLabels or JPanels myself

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks for your advice, I implemented the Listener to the canvas extending JPanel and it works

Answer (score 0):

I would advise that you add the listener to the components held by the main JPanel so you can get individual clicked components more easily. For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TicTacToePanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String ROW = "row";
    private static final String COL = "col";
    private static final Color BKGRD1 = new Color(230, 230, 230);
    private static final Color BKGRD2 = new Color(180, 180, 180);
    private static final Dimension CELL_SIZE = new Dimension(80, 80);
    private JPanel[][] panelGrid = new JPanel[3][3];
    
    
    public TicTacToePanel() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3, 1, 1));
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        
        MyMouse myMouse = new MyMouse();
         
        for (int i = 0; i < panelGrid.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < panelGrid[i].length; j++) {
                JPanel cellPanel = new JPanel();
                cellPanel.putClientProperty(ROW, i);
                cellPanel.putClientProperty(COL, j);
                cellPanel.setPreferredSize(CELL_SIZE);
                cellPanel.setBackground(BKGRD1);
                cellPanel.addMouseListener(myMouse);
                add(cellPanel);
                panelGrid[i][j] = cellPanel;
            }
        }
    }
    
    class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            JPanel cell = (JPanel) e.getComponent();
            if (cell == null) {
                return;
            }
            
            Color background = cell.getBackground().equals(BKGRD1) ? BKGRD2 : BKGRD1;
            cell.setBackground(background);
            int row = (int) cell.getClientProperty(ROW);
            int col = (int) cell.getClientProperty(COL);
            System.out.printf("cell row & column: [%d, %d]%n", row, col);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            TicTacToePanel mainPanel = new TicTacToePanel();

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(mainPanel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

}
```

Here, I create a 2D array of JPanels:

```
private JPanel[][] panelGrid = new JPanel[3][3];
```

and then in the main JPanel's constructor,

1. create individual "cell" JPanels in a nested for loop, adding them to the main JPanel
2. Adding my mouse listener to each individual cell.
3. This way, I can get each individual clicked cell cleanly and easily

```
public TicTacToePanel() {
    // ....
    
    // my mouse listener
    MyMouse myMouse = new MyMouse();
    
    // create cells and fill my grid with cells
    for (int i = 0; i < panelGrid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < panelGrid[i].length; j++) {
            JPanel cellPanel = new JPanel();
            
            // gives each cell identifying information
            cellPanel.putClientProperty(ROW, i);
            cellPanel.putClientProperty(COL, j);
            
            cellPanel.setPreferredSize(CELL_SIZE);
            cellPanel.setBackground(BKGRD1);
            
            // add the same mouse listener to all cells
            cellPanel.addMouseListener(myMouse);
            add(cellPanel); // add it to the main JPanel
            panelGrid[i][j] = cellPanel; // and to a holding array
        }
    }
}
```

The mouse listener is simple:

```
class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // get the cell clicked
        JPanel cell = (JPanel) e.getComponent();
        // make sure it's not null
        if (cell == null) {
            return;
        }
        
        // then do stuff to it
        Color background = cell.getBackground().equals(BKGRD1) ? BKGRD2 : BKGRD1;
        cell.setBackground(background);
        int row = (int) cell.getClientProperty(ROW);
        int col = (int) cell.getClientProperty(COL);
        System.out.printf("cell row & column: [%d, %d]%n", row, col);
    }
}
```